# как выявить циклические зависимости при сериализации в java?

Tags: java, serialize

как выявить циклические зависимости при сериализации в java?

Comment: зачем вам надо их выявить?

Comment: Приложение падает с StackOverflow error

Comment: java автоматически обрабатывает циклические ссылки. вы уваерены, что это причина?

Comment: Нет, не уверен, пытаюсь разобраться в причине плавающего stackoverflowError. Моя мысль в том, что при попытке сериализовать мои модели, в моделях присуствуют цикл. ссылки, от этого приложение и падает

Comment: java умеет работать с циклическим ссылками. проверьте ваш код в отладчике и в профайлере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обходной путь тут, это использовать @JsonIgnore